# Change confidence level in t test (inside of by()) in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I need to change the value of confidence level in t.test in by()

```
res<-by(HUS[,1], HUS$air.conditioning, FUN=t.test)
```

Where i can provide conf.level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anonymous/lamdba function (`function(x)`

```
res <- by(HUS[,1], HUS$air.conditioning, FUN = 
         function(x) t.test(x, conf.level = 0.90))
```

---

Or specify the named argument

```
res <- by(HUS[,1], HUS$air.conditioning, FUN=t.test, conf.level = 0.90)
```

NOTE: Specifying the named argument may not work in all the functions e.g. `ave`

---

Check with reproducible example

```
res1 <- by(mtcars[, "mpg"], mtcars$cyl, FUN = t.test, conf.level = 0.90)
res2 <- by(mtcars[, "mpg"], mtcars$cyl, FUN = function(x) t.test(x,  conf.level = 0.90))
```

```
> res1 <- lapply(res1, function(x) {x$data.name <- "x"; x})
> all.equal(res1, res2, check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```